# Saltstack iterate through second level pillar data

Tags: python, saltstack

I might be missing something or this might just be the wrong way to layout pillar data.

I want to iterate through the second level of pillar data.

Pillar example:

```
repo:
     Option1:
        version1:
            display_name: "abcde"
        version2:
            display_name: "fghij"
     Option2:
        version1:
            display_name: "klmn"`
```

Sls:

```
{% for version, versioninfo in salt['pillar.get']('repo', {}).iteritems() %}
{{ versioninfo[] }}{{ versioninfo[]['display_name'] }}
{% endfor %}`
```

I want to return each version and display name, effectively ignoring the first level of pillar data.
Obviously the above jinja does not work, but is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You need two levels of iteration. `.iteritems()` returns the key and the values (items) for that key. Your first iteration will give you access to option names and versions. Your second iteration will give you the display_name.

```
{% for option, versions in salt['pillar.get']('repo', {}).iteritems() %}
  {% for version, info in versions.iteritems() %}
    {{ version }}:{{ info['display_name'] }} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

OR you could do this:

```
{% for option, versions in salt['pillar.get']('repo', {}).iteritems() %}
  {% for version in versions %}
    {{ version }}:{{ versions[version]['display_name'] }} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```